# How do I know which Maven Dependency Version to pick?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Java Web developing. I am learning how to use Spring Boot, Spring MVC with Eclipse. I have tried to build several small projects, mainly to practice setting up developing environment. I am having trouble figuring out which Version I should use for my dependencies. For example, I used `http://start.spring.io/` to create my project and import them to my IDE (Eclipse), for dependencies, I used Web and DevTool. After Downloading, extracting and importing the project I have an error like this
[image]

I did some digging and found this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

It is running on `2.0.2.RELEASE` which is the newest version. After I downgraded it to `2.0.1.RELEASE` and updated the project, that problem is gone, and now I have another problem. I tried to run the project and I got this error
[image]

So I went ahead and downgraded that parent dependency all the way to `1.4.3.RELEASE`, and it works!!! This is frustrating me because I can't follow a lot of online example due to this issue. Isn’t newer version should have fixed all these error?

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the download dependencies are borked. Do a `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` or whatever you use to run your maven goals. Then rebuild the project this will re-download the jars.

Comment: How do i do this, please?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, I tried this and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

For 2.0.2.RELEASE, as per the error, add slf4j Logger

```
<properties>
<slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
</properties>
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Refresh Maven, and do a clean build. Hope, that would solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you suggest to add an out-dated version of SLF4J? Which might lead to all sorts of issues. The Slf4j dependencies are there by default.

Comment: I was using that version. You could try the latest one.

Answer (score -1):

If i were you, i would use the latest version 2.0.2.RELEASE (make sure you are using Java 1.8 or above) and then change the import to: `import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;`

Then run the whole maven lifecycle, clean, validate, compile, package, verify and install.

I had the same issue and it was resolved with this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this please?

Comment: If you r using Intellij just use the Maven view, expand the Lifecycle and then run the ones i mentioned above... if you are using any other, then i would use cmd... running mvc (each command mentioned above)

Comment: `SpringApplication` is not the same was `@SpringBootApplication`. Both are part of Spring Boot.